# How to update string with Ecto

Tags: elixir

I thought string concat was `<>` but I can't get it to work in the code below. I get an error

> Only literal binaries and strings are allowed, dynamic values need to be explicitly interpolated in queries with ^

I've added `^` but it still does not work

```
  def delete(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
    card = Repo.get!(Card, id)

    # Look for any cards that have chosen one as master
    # Update name to deleted card + version name
    # remove master_id
    query =
        from(c in Card,
             where: c.master_id == ^id,
             update: [set: [ estimate_name: (^card.estimate_name <> ^c.estimate_name),
                             master_id: 0 ]])
        |> Repo.update_all([])
```

There is something strange about how the code is interpreted as my string fields are been read as functions I think:

`<<^card.estimate_name()::binary, ^c.estimate_name()::binary>>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As one of the two parts you want to concatenate is a column from the table, you'll need the database to do the concatenation.

There is no function in Ecto to do this, so you'll have to use `fragment`. This should work on SQLite and PostgreSQL (I'm not sure about MySQL):

```
update: [set: [estimate_name: fragment("? || ?", ^card.estimate_name, c.estimate_name),
               master_id: 0]]
```

Comment: I tried to replicate this in a new instance. `from(p in Project, where: p.id == ^id, update: [ set: [ jobs: fragment("? || ?", ^job_id, p.jobs) ] ])`, where `job_id` is an integer and `p.jobs` is an array of integers. I'm getting error: ` Postgrex expected a list that can be encoded/cast to type "_int4", got 2.`. I want to add 2 to the array

Comment: You want to add the item 2 to the array or add 2 to every item of the array?

Comment: `ARRAY[4,5,6]` --> `2 || ARRAY[4,5,6]` c.f. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-array.html

Comment: Ok, I just tried that. That error seems to be weird. A workaround you can use for now is `fragment("? || ?", ^[job_id], p.jobs)`. This might be a bug in Postgrex.